# A reverse kind of string compare using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I've been searching for this answer all over internet but so far no luck. So I need to consult the smart and nice people here. This is my first time asking a question here, so I hope I am doing this right and not repeating the question.

For all the examples I saw, it's the search string that is a substring of what's stored in the Core Data. On the other hand, I want to achieve the following:

The strings stored in core data are actually sub-strings. I want to do a search by getting all core data rows that have substrings belong to the provided search string.

For ex: 
In core data, I have "AB", "BC","ABC","ABCDEF","GH", "ABA"
And in the app I do a search by providing the super-string: "ABCDEF", the result will return "AB","BC","ABC","ABCDEF" but not "GH", "ABA" because these two sub-strings don't belong to the super-string.

How should I setup my predicateWithFormat statement?

This wont' work cuz it's doing the opposite:

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"substring LIKE[c] %@", @"ABCDEF"];
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reverse of `CONTAINS` will not work. Also, you will not be able to use `LIKE` because you would have to take the attribute you are searching and transform it into a wildcard string.

The way to go is to use `MATCHES` because you can use regular expressions. First, transform your search string into a regex by affixing a `*` after each letter. Then form the predicate.

This solution has been tested to work with your example.

```
NSString *string= @"ABCDEF";
NSMutableString *new = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    [new appendFormat:@"%c*", [string characterAtIndex:i]]; 
}
// new is now @"A*B*C*D*E*F*";
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"stringAttribute matches %@", new];
```

where `stringAttribute` in the predicate is the name of your `NSString` attribute of your managed object.

Comment: Wow this is advance stuff. Thanks it works! Now I gotta try to understand how it works here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mundi, I'm not sure what you mean by "the reverse CONTAINS" won't work.  The predicate I provided in my answer does work, I've updated my answer to show the code for using that predicate with core data.

Comment: I tried your version, without correctly retrieving the substring matches. Obviously, that was before your edit. After your edit, I could edit my answer etc. *ad infinitum*. Thanks for your correction, anyway.

Comment: Now I tried your new version - it still does not work. ('NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance). Sorry.

Comment: Yah, that was the error I got, too. It seems the first parameter in predicate statement has to be a path key (i.e. the actual field name in the database)

Comment: After a closer look, this solution is close to what I'm looking for, but not exactly. With this solution of converting the string to, for ex, @"A?B?C?D?E?F?" will match ABC, EF, ... (this is what I want) no issue. But it will also match ABD (ignored C) - That's not what I want.

In short, I want to match all valid records stored in Core Data that are substrings of the supplied super string. Any ideas how this can be done using predicate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains self",@"ABCDEF"];
```

You would use it like this in core data:

```
-(IBAction)doFetch:(id)sender {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Expense" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains desc",@"ABCDEF"];
    NSArray *answer = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",answer);
}
```

In this example, "desc" is an attribute of the entity "Expense".  This correctly retrieves only the rows where "desc" is a substring of "ABCDEF".

Comment: @Kjuly, it doesn't matter whether its upper or lower case.

Comment: yep, but I'd like to use upper case for reserved words. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried doing "contains" before as well. It seems the first token cannot be the string. The code doesn't seem to even execute if I do that. But I'll give it another try when I get a chance. Btw, what does the reserve word SELF represent? Thanks.

Comment: Another follow-up question is what exactly does "LIKE" do? I tried doing the following and it seems LIKE is doing exact string comparison:

"ABC" LIKE "ABC" -> TRUE
"ABCD" LIKE "ABC" -> FALSE
"ABC" LIKE "ABCD" -> FALSE

Thanks for heping out with newbie questions

Comment: SELF represents the object that will be passed to the predicate -- so if you use the predicate to filter an array (with filteredArrayUsingPredicate:) SELF will be each object in the array. LIKE means the left hand expression equals the right hand expression, but you can include wildcards to expand the scope.  Have a look at Apple's Predicate Programming Guide.

Comment: How can `SELF` match the string attribute of a managed object??