# Filtering a large NSArray with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I have an array containing 170k strings (words in a dictionary), and a string, looking something like "glapplega". I'm trying to extract the word "apple" from the string (with "apple" being a word in the array). I also need to make sure that the extracted word is at least 3 characters. The code I have right now is the following:

```
NSPredicate *wordPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"'%@' contains[cd] SELF", string];
NSPredicate *lengthPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.length > 2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[wordPredicate, lengthPredicate]];
return [_words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:lengthPredicate];
```

The length predicate works on it's own, but the word predicate does not (it returns an empty array, despite "apple" being a word in the array).

I suspect that there might be a problem with using SELF as the right expression in the predicate, as all the examples I found have it as the left expression, although I have no way of confirming this.

**Edit**: I'm aware that this can likely be accomplished with regexs (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941811/a-reverse-kind-of-string-compare-using-nspredicate)), but was hoping there would be a way around this, as regexs can be slow with such a large dataset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A reverse kind of string compare using NSPredicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941811/a-reverse-kind-of-string-compare-using-nspredicate)

Comment: @MCKapur I saw that, was hoping there would be some way around that as regexs can be kind of slow on such a large array.

Comment: there are many many ways to do this, with predicates.. if you get stuck on predicates iterate yourself, and look at NSString indexOfSubstring... if you don't want to do that drop down to C and use strstr/strnstr

Comment: What are you trying to do ? I think the above predicate is wrong. It should be like NSPredicate *wordPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", string]; Check your syntax.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I'm afraid iterating through the list itself may be fairly slow, as there are hundreds of thousands of items.

Comment: @GradyPlayer `indexOfString`will not meet his requirements, he needs string contain matches

Comment: @insane-36 I'm trying to find which items in the array can be found in the input string.

Comment: @insane-36 He actually needs it the other way around, which is why it isn't working.

Comment: well no matter what magic you use, something will have to iterate it.. unless you do some very complicated indexing, which is possible, but I assume out of the scope of this project

Comment: @GradyPlayer Right, but I'm assuming by using a predicate to filter the array it will be significantly faster than if I were to iterate through it myself and compare.

Comment: well then you need to copy your array and do a filteredArrayUsing... then do indexOfString...

Comment: test, dont assume. fast iteration is fast.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I agree with you. My answer below did not deserve a down vote when my theory was not tested and yet concluded to be 'slow'. And it's sophisticated too. However, Grady, again, he's not looking for complete matches, so how would `indexOfString` work exactly?

Comment: @GradyPlayer The iteration actually worked much faster than I anticipated. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: This question is **not a duplicate** of [A reverse kind of string compare using NSPredicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941811/a-reverse-kind-of-string-compare-using-nspredicate), which is about a *Core Data* fetch request, while this is about filtering an NSArray. Predicates used for Core Data fetch requests are much more restricted, and, as @insane-36 showed below, the answer given there does not apply here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving this problem is easy if you iterate the array yourself using a block predicate. At some point a formatted NSPredicate would have to boil down to this, so there shouldn't be much of a performance hit. `-[NSString rangeOfString:]` can be used to test for inclusion of the string.

```
return [_words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL (id evaluatedString, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return string.length > 2 && [string rangeOfString:evaluatedString].location != NSNotFound;
}]];
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize this was a thing. Thanks!

Comment: @PenmanRoss I think you're missing a bracket on the last line.

Comment: Oh, and the last condition should be !=, not ==. Thanks again

Comment: um `&& [string rangeOfString:evaluatedString].location == NSNotFound` ?

Comment: @futurevilla216 Thanks. Fixed missing bracket.

Answer (score 3):

You know what your above assumption and predicate is perfectly valid. The only thing that you have been doing wrong is quotations. Reformat your predicate and make it like this,

```
  NSArray * array = @[@"Apple", @"lega", @"foo", @"bar"];
  NSString *string = @"glapplega";
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[cd] SELF and SELF.length > 2", string];
  NSLog(@"%@",[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);

(
    Apple,
    lega
)
```

When you specify the format and supply the string to the format, the predicate places the quotes by itself. So, you have been mistaking over here.

Comment: @LennyK Are you sure that this does not work. I have tried it with few different cases and it seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define rchar (rand() % ('z'-'a') + 'a')

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSMutableArray * mar = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i<170000; i++)
    {
        NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c",rchar, rchar, rchar, rchar];
        [mar addObject:str];
    }
    NSString * bigStr = @"asdfghjkl;loiuytrdcvcdrtgvfrtghvcftyghvfghcfdtyjghvncdfjtygmvcnfhjghjkgfhdgsxgrecrvtbkunhlmnhubkujvytchrtxgrecdjvbyhnkbjgcfhvyjhbghnkbjchgdfvbghnukbytvjycterwxrzewxcevfbjnkmjohgytreytwexkutckhtdtcfhvjgkjmhgcjhewwzsserdp9dlkuydssqwsxdchvggjhmgbj";
    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
    NSArray * marFiltered = [mar filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [bigStr rangeOfString:evaluatedObject].length>2;
    }]];
    NSLog(@"found %lu items in %f seconds", (unsigned long)[marFiltered count], -[start timeIntervalSinceNow]);
}
```

output:

```
2014-05-11 09:09:53.048 170k[89396:303] found 85 items in 0.542431 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try two options for defining the predicate. A format string and a block. Here is a bit of code that demonstrates both. I've played a bit with both and can share that the performance is the same. I've only had the patience to run it with a max value of INT32_MAX/2 (a lot of items).

Here goes. Hope this clarifies and helps:

```
    NSString* searchString = @"AB0";
    NSUInteger capacity = 1000000;
    NSMutableArray* array  = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSLog(@"Fillling array with %lu UUIDS. Be patient.", (unsigned long)capacity);
    NSUInteger batch = 0;
    for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < capacity; i++ ) {
        [array setObject:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] atIndexedSubscript:i];
        if (i != 0 && i % (capacity / 10) == 0 ) {
            NSLog(@"Completed %lu%%", (unsigned long)++batch * 10);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Done.");

    NSPredicate* formatPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@ AND SELF.length > 3", searchString];
    NSLog(@"Filtering with predicate: %@", formatPredicate);
    NSArray* formatArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:formatPredicate];
    NSLog(@"Got %lu results.", formatArray.count);

    NSPredicate* blockPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSString* theString = evaluatedObject;
        return theString.length > 3 && [theString rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound;
    }];

    NSLog(@"Filtering with predicate: %@", blockPredicate);
    NSArray* blockArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:blockPredicate];
    NSLog(@"Got %lu results.", blockArray.count);
```

PS: I wouldn't run this on a phone if you are using big numbers line INT32_MAX :)