# Predicate for range of NString in a Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array(`NSArray`) let's say

```
NSArray *cityArry = @[@"Chennai", @"Mumbai", @"Kolkata"];
```

For example I have mentioned the `NSArray` with 3 objects, but actually in runtime I have an array which contain more than 1000 objects.

Now I have the string(`NSString`) "chennai Tnagar"

```
NSString *scanedStr = @"Chennai Tnagar";
```

So, now I want to find out that the whether range of `scanedStr` contain in `cityArry`. For example I should get output as `@"Chennai"` from the `cityArry`.

I know we can do this by looping the `NSArray` and by using `rangeofstring` we can get the output. Since I have more than 1000 objects I don't want to do the looping. Please guide me and help me out how to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does your algorithm will match "Che"?

Comment: No, I don't want to get the output when the 'scannedstr' is 'che. I want to get it when NSSting 'scannedstr' is like 'chennai sometext', 'sometext chennai' etc.

Comment: but what about "Tnagar"? "Tnagar sometext" and "sometext Tnagar" will be matched too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could basically split the string and search for the array on the cityArry.

```
NSString *scannedStr = @"Chennai Tnager";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF in[cd] %@", [scannedStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];

[cityArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

Comment: WOW... Thanks a lot.. It works like a magic :) But my concern, is this the optimised way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, predicates are the best ways to filter collection in Objective C.

Comment: @PrashanthRajagopalan: An explicit loop can be *faster* than a predicate, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/21158730/1187415 .

Comment: Allow me to introduce some extended test data for your algorithm: `cityArry = @[@"Chennai", @"New York"]` and `scannedStr = @"New York City"`. Does this algorithm produce the intended result?

Comment: @MartinR in the house! I am nearly certain that the information in my answer is from a comment or answer made by you to another question. Any chance you could dig it up? I can't find it.

Comment: Yes it does, it should actually match the "New York" in the array, since the substrings "New", "York" from scannedStr matches to it.

Comment: @insane-36 Have you tried to run it? It does not produce what I would expect (to match "New York" in the array) when I run it, but I may have made a mistake.

Comment: @Monolo Nice Catch. I checked it. It doesn't work for 'New York City'.  In that case, your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I am certain that this is a duplicate of another answer, but I can't find it. If anybody can, please close this as a dupe.

Anyway, the `IN` operator works nicely on strings. Apparently it is undocumented, so you will have to decide if you want to rely on it:

```
NSArray *cityArray = @[@"Chennai",@"Mumbai",@"Kolkata"];

NSString *scannedStr = @"Chennai Tnagar";

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF IN[cd] %@", scannedStr];

NSArray *result = [cityArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: pred];
```

This solution has the advantage of keeping the object of the predicate on the left, which I happen to find easier to read - but as mentioned, it is not documented.

In case you wish to use a documented construct, you can swap the order of the predicate and use a normal `CONTAINS`:

```
pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%@ CONTAINS[cd] SELF", scannedStr];
```

Comment: I did post a similar answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23594103/1187415), but I deleted it later because this behaviour is undocumented, and because @insane-36 showed in his answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23594199/1187415) to the same question that this can be achieved with a simpler documented predicate.

Comment: @Monolo Your answer is perfect. But you are saying it is undocumented. Can I use it ?

Comment: @PrashanthRajagopalan Actually, I got led a bit astray by @MartinR's from yesterday which uses the elegant `IN`. You can just turn the predicate around and use the documented `CONTAINS` in the format string, like this: `@"%@ CONTAINS[cd] SELF"`. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you make use of SQL query `like` by using sqlite3 as a database of the list of all cities you have. Its a bit painful implementing a database but it solves the problem I think.